# Help Me With css() method

Tags: jquery

So, I am trying to change background of two input fields after the document loads. I use this jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#login').css('background', "url('login-bg.gif') 3em center no-repeat");
    $('#password').css('background', "url('password-bg.gif') 3em center no-repeat");

});
```

I have looked at the code in the Firebug and it seems alright. However, the input fields don't change their background.

If I just set their background in the stylesheet it works (I want to do it with jquery though because I want to change the background of the fields after various events take place).

Comment: do you keep stylesheets, images and the page you display in the same folder?

Comment: try using double quotes to wrap your selectors and "background" or "background-image".  jQuery is probably handling some error internally because of mismatched quotes.  Since you're using single quotes in your url option, you'll have to use double quotes for the jquery options.  However, the url option doesn't require quotes, so you can remove those single quotes.

Comment: I think the single quotes are not required but recommended. I see them in most online css tutorials.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to use

```
css("background-image", "url(login-bg.gif)");
css("background-position", "3em center");
css("background-repeat", "no-repeat");
```

OR rather

```
css( { "background-image"    : "url(login-bg.gif)",
       "background-position" : "3em center", 
       "background-repeat"   : "no-repeat"
     }
);
```

First sentence on the [docs page](http://docs.jquery.com/CSS/css)

"Shorthand CSS properties (e.g. margin, background, border) are not supported."

**ALSO** the path to the image should **not** be quoted.

Answer (score 1):

The images should be in the same path as your page.

Answer (score 1):

I tested the below code in both FF 3.5.7 and IE 7 and it seems to work. Sure you check already...but typo somewhere?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head>
        <title>Test</title>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.0/jquery.min.js" /></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#login').css('background', "url('login-bg.gif') 3em center no-repeat");
                $('#password').css('background', "url('password-bg.gif') 3em center no-repeat");
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 0.8em; margin: 3em; background-color: #f1f1f1;">

    <div><input id="login" type="text" /></div>

    <br />

    <div><input id="password" type="text" /></div>

    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure the image paths are right
2. Remove the single quotes inside the CSS `url` style, i.e. `url(login-bg.gif)`